# When does a principal divisor have degree 0?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

We know that on a smooth curve over an algebraically closed field principal divisors have degree 0. This holds true also for the projective space over any field (in this case equality holds too).

My question is the following. Are there any other interesting cases in which it happens? If not, what is an example of proper or even projective scheme in which this fails?

Comment: There is no notion of degree for divisors (principal or not)  on a proper scheme, unless you provide the scheme with some supplementary structure. What would the degree be ??